# Get sum of all when date is between the two given values

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
date          val

2016-1-1       8
2016-2-1       10
2016-1-2       30
2016-1-3       30
```

Now, I have two dates coming in from a different table, let's call them `fromdate` and `two date`

If fromdate was 1, `2016-1-1` and Todate was `2016-1-2`, I need 8+30 = 38 as the final value

I need to check

SUM(val) of all those values dates corresponding to which are between the fromdate and twodate.

I tried this:

```
SELECT nr.sku AS ParentSKU
SUM(gasessiondata.sessions) as visitsWhenSKUWasOnline
FROM
Erp.new_ranking nr
LEFT JOIN 
Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline ndo
ON
ndo.sku = nr.sku
JOIN
gadb.gasessiondata gasessiondata
ON 1=1
WHERE
ndo.FromDate Is NOT NULL
AND 
ndo.ToDate IS NOT NULL
AND
gasessiondata.date >= ndo.FromDate
AND 
gasessiondata.date <= ndo.ToDate
GROUP BY nr.sku
```

but ofcourse this isn't correct.

Comment: @Strawberry: Dates are stored as date data type only.

Comment: OK, so now I don't understand why the from and to values would be coming from a table !?!?

Comment: gasessiondata would give me sessions on a particular date. The other table gives me two dates that I would need to check the total number of visits between.so my query basically gives me the sum of values for which date is between the two given dates . @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to pass the dates in join expression, but in a subquery you will get the sum:

```
SELECT ndo.sku ParentSKU,
  (
    SELECT SUM(gasessiondata.sessions) as s
    FROM gasessiondata
    gasessiondata.date >= ndo.FromDate
    AND 
    gasessiondata.date <= ndo.ToDate
  ) as visitsWhenSKUWasOnline
FROM Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline ndo
```

I don't understand your table structure and your tables are not clearly described, but I think the adobe query will helps.